# How to implement unit test for a simple C function that returns binary data?

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I want to implement some very simple C/C++ unit tests for a function that is supposed to compress or decompress some data.

Mainly the input is a binary block and the output is also a binary block. The binary blocks should be less than 50 bytes, probably having 5-6 pairs.

I am looking for a solution that would preferably not require third party libraries. If it would require this one should be very small/simple.

Comment: It is unclear whether the 3rd party libraries referenced would help implement unit-tests or provide the same functionality (to be tested against them, then). Could you precise ?

Comment: couldn't help it: sorin 6,666 (devilish)!

Comment: not any more, now I'm above the devil ;)

Answer (score 1):

> "I am looking for a solution that would not require third party libraries."

Just write the unit-test function, it's easy: Create a function which will call the to-be-testet-function with different arguments and compare the result with the expected outputs. Add a function-pointer to that testing-function to a global function-pointer-array in which you store all testing-functions so that you can run all of them on demand.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow you need to validate your functions and the only solutions that I can think of are:

- use some 3rd party libraries (known to work in practice)
- use some data sequences for which you know exactly what the output should look like

Comment: Using the 3rd party library known to work in practice is only useful to generate the dataset, unless you plan on doing fuzzy testing (but this is slightly different since the results are generally not reproductible).

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of unit tests I could think of.
1. To check if the output is correct or not. For this you could try with inputs for which the output is known. In the unit code you could compare the output from the method with the known output.
2. To check regressions alone. I have used these kind of tests in some kind of legacy codebase. Here your functions are somehow proven (maybe tested with other means). But, when somebody makes some changes to this code you need to ensure that the main output is not either not corrupted. For this you could call the method in a particular build where you were sure that the function was working fine and capture this output as baseline. Later you could write a unit test driver to call the method and compare the output with the baseline output in all later builds. But you need to remember to update the baseline when the function was modified intentionally to modify the output later.

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware that this is a very old question, but I happen to come here with the same problem.
I'm going to assume that the third party dependency was for a tool in order to compare binary data, not the unit test tool itself (I'm assuming this because is my same requirement).

What I ended up doing was something like this:

```
  char result_buffer[] = "“jJ";
  auto n               = memcmp(result_buffer, your_function(), sizeof(char) * 3);
```

In order to get the value for result_buffer, I actually go with the debugger and get that value from there. This way i can ensure that it's correct.
After that, the only left to do was to check if n was 0 or not with you unit testing tool.